# Using function name as parameter of setState method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx, setstate

my question seems to be quite simple. But in the code below, how is it possible to use "prevState" as function without coding the function ?

```
handleAddOne() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        counter: prevState.counter + 1
      };
    });
  }
```

`
Here you can see all the code in which handleAddOne() is include.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
    this.handleAddOne = this.handleAddOne.bind(this);
  }
  handleAddOne() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        counter: prevState.counter + 1
      };
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Counter: {this.state.counter}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleAddOne}>Add One</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, rootElement);
```

I didn't try anything special, just need explanation.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you asking why your code works and why it's possible to pass a function to `setState()`? Or are you asking how to achieve some type of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

How about using "React Hook" like "useState, useEffect()". it's can checked your value, and you can start function and setState also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, but my purpose here is to know if prevState is a parameter of the function passed into setState, or the name of the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question properly because you DID code the function when you wrote:

```
prevState => {
  return {
    counter: prevState.counter + 1
  };
}
```

This is an arrow function definition. You can store it in a variable and call it later or pass it as an argument to another function without storing it; as you did with `this.setState`. You can read more about js arrow functions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp). Also, this is a recursive function that calls itself, and you can read about it [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-recursion-in-javascript/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped me. I didn't know what is "prevState", my purpose here is to know if prevState is a parameter of the function passed into setState, or the name of the function itself.

Comment: @Edharad Glad I could help. `prevState` is the parameter of this arrow function. In other words, `setState` has a function as its parameter and this function has a single parameter called `prevstate`. the second function (which is the parameter of `setstate`) is an "Anonymous function" too and therefore has no name associated with it. You can read more about anonymous functions [here](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-anonymous-functions/).